# Flutter Icons Call From Database

Tags: flutter

I have icon-name in my database called (for example) "favorite", "people, "home", etc. The code :

```
Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 25)
```

How can I replace that to string? I have tried flutter_icons,  material_design_icons_flutter, etc.

```
Icon(Icons.icon.name, size: 25) //icon.name is the method to call the string from API database
```

Hope you get what I was trying to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `getIconUsingPrefix` of package https://pub.dev/packages/icons_helper and `FutureBuilder` 
Demo code simulate retrieve DB dealy

```
Future<String> iconName() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {});
    return Future.value("favorite");
  }
...
FutureBuilder(
    future: _future,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      ...
        case ConnectionState.done:
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            ...
          } else {
            return Icon(getIconUsingPrefix(name: snapshot.data),
                size: 25.0);
          }
      }
    })
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:icons_helper/icons_helper.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo + Icon Helper Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<String> _future;

  Future<String> iconName() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {});
    return Future.value("favorite");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = iconName();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder(
                future: _future,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.none:
                      return Text('none');
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    case ConnectionState.active:
                      return Text('');
                    case ConnectionState.done:
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text(
                          '${snapshot.error}',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Icon(getIconUsingPrefix(name: snapshot.data),
                            size: 25.0);
                      }
                  }
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a map with 'iconName' as key, and IconData as value. and after fetching iconName from db use it to get IconData;